# HTML: supporting multiple upload buttons in one form

Tags: javascript

I have a form where there's multiple elements (number 0..n)

each element has a readonly input, and an "upload" button.
I want each upload button to open the file dialog, let the user choose a fill and corresponding input field with the full path chosen.

when the button is clicked for each element, I call a javascript method with the ID of the input field corresponding to it.

```
function upload(theID) {         
  var fileSelector = $('<input type="file" />');
  fileSelector.click();
}
```

This function gets called with the correct ID, opens a file selection dialog, but that's about it...

My questions are:

1. How do I get a function call when the file is chosen?
2. How do I associate the file chosen with "theID" it was called for so that I can update the right input #ID with the file/path chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you try to use the [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) library. It supports uploading multiple files by default.